# Can an "Emotional Need" for a camera be justified?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

Can an "emotional need" for a new body be justified? I'm upgrading from an XTI to a 7D after 6-7 years.  I have not used the XTI to its fullest, yet I want the upgrade.  Am I fooling myself thinking that a "better"  camera will force me to become a better photographer, because of less scene-settings on the front dial?  If I have to ask, have I already answered the question?  Your thoughts?

I understand this is an open ended question - I was just hoping for some words before I make the investment...

Thanks

Comment: While I appreciate the sentiment, and I do this a lot as well, it's not really suitable to the site I think. This isn't a discussion forum and that question series is a discussion topic. You might want to try using the chat features, you now have sufficient rep (assuming you don't get some down votes) to chat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I justify a new camera purchase when I'm not a top photographer?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29517/how-can-i-justify-a-new-camera-purchase-when-im-not-a-top-photographer)

Comment: This also may be helpful: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21317/what-factors-should-i-consider-to-decide-if-its-worth-upgrading-to-a-pro-leve

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is totally justified. If a new camera makes you happier and you can afford it, then get it. Any technical improvement in your images  is immaterial if the new camera increases your confidence or the enjoyment of taking photos.

Answer (score 2):

New gear can inspire you creatively, so I'm going to say, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Start shooting in manual exclusively before the upgrade. Then upgrade and keep doing it on manual, including choosing different focus points. Then you will feel you got your money's worth and that it is not just an emotional satisfaction :)

Comment: What does shooting in manual mode have to do with it? Indeed, the 7D has a lot of great automatic features; how does ignoring them help you get greater value from your purchase? Should the OP also turn off autofocus to get even more value? Smart photographers learn to use all the tools at their disposal effectively. Just sayin'. :-)

Comment: I have had the 400D and shot full manual on it and it's a bitch. Then I got 40D and it changed my life :) Going from full auto to better full auto won't be "felt" as significantly. You'd have to take a lot of pictures and start noticing how difficult situations are easier to get right. But the ergonomics of controlling everything while you look through that huge bright viewfinder will be felt instantaneously.